# Install a single specific package from future distribution

Tags: apt, partial-upgrade

I'm currently using precise. I need to upgrade a certain package (namely [bind9](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bind9) and it's dependencies) to a newer version, which is currently found in raring (alfa at the time of writing this). How to do it ?

What will happen if I just add to my sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

Will the next `apt-get update / apt-get upgrade`, upgrade most of my system to raring then ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to mix repositories like that you should use pinning.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto for details.

When pinning, you install a single package and as few dependencies as possible.

Without pinning, `sudo apt-get upgrade` will update (upgrade) many or all your packages and very likely will cause breakage.

In general, unless you have a lot of experience with apt, mixing repositories, even with pinning is inadvisable.

Better to find a ppa or use backports.

My advice is that you use Craven's ppa.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

IMO, if a package is not available, I agree with the advice to build from source as, IMO, it is less likely to cause irreparable harm to the system.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it will upgrade all the packages to the newest version found in the raring repository.

You should try adding a specific [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hauke/+archive/bind9) for the bind9 package.

Comment: There's no PPA for precise there

Comment: @Sandman4 - If you look at the your link, you'll see that the version in Raring for Bind9 is 9.9.2. That is also the version available in every repository found in the one Craven has linked. Therefore, you probably don't actually need to install it from the future distribution, as Precise very likely has that version. If you want the most recent version, you'll have to compile the source yourself from [the ISC website](https://www.isc.org/software/bind), though I doubt you'll see much difference unless you're looking for a specific bug fix.

Comment: I am looking for a specific bugfix - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bind9/+bug/1085593.

Comment: Precise (and quantal) have 9.8.1. Raring have 9.9.2 (see my link)

Comment: I already provided you a PPA with bind 9.9.2. You can add it via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<user>/<ppa-name>`.

If it doesn't work try [this](https://launchpad.net/~malcscott/+archive/bind9.9). It is a little newer.

If that doesn't work either, search for a PPA with the exact version of bind you need.